# How to subtract the minimum from a column in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to find the elapsed time since the first time an event was observed. For this I saved each observation in a CSV file. Each event is identified by a unique hash.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
from pandas import *
from bz2 import BZ2File
events = DataFrame.from_csv(BZ2File('events.csv.bz2', 'r'), sep='\t', header=0, index_col=None)
m = events.groupby('hash')['timestamp'].min()
```

at this point I have a Series indexed by the hash and the timestamp of the first observation.
How would I use this to get the time offset for each row in the events DataFrame (simply timestamp - min(timestamp))?

Answer (score 2):

Let me setup a toy example here:

```
In [38]: rng = pd.date_range('2012-8-1', freq='T', periods=100)
In [39]: hashes = np.random.randint(0, 10, len(rng))
In [40]: obs = np.arange(len(rng))
In [41]: df = DataFrame({'hash' : hashes, 'timestamp' : rng.asobject},
   ....:                index=obs)
```

Now to get the time difference for each hash:

```
In [42]: grouped = df.set_index('hash', append=True).groupby(level='hash')

In [44]: grouped.transform(lambda x: x-x.min())
Out[44]:
        timestamp
   hash
0  3      0:00:00
1  5      0:00:00
2  1      0:00:00
3  8      0:00:00
4  6      0:00:00
5  8      0:02:00
6  1      0:04:00
7  7      0:00:00
8  3      0:08:00
9  5      0:08:00
10 8      0:07:00
11 1      0:09:00
12 2      0:00:00
...
...
...
94 2      1:22:00
95 6      1:31:00
96 1      1:34:00
97 0      1:21:00
98 8      1:35:00
99 0      1:23:00
```